# Could not open database file (Misuse) SqlLiteAsyncConnection

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am getting the exception "Could not open database file: [path] (Misuse)" when trying to open my SQLite connection.

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms application and am doing the debugging in UWP which is where I'm getting the exception.

The constructor to my data store class creates the connection and the tables:

```
internal static string DBPath
{
    get
    {
        const string FILE_NAME = "TheRandomizer.db3";
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), FILE_NAME);
        }
        else
        {
             return Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, FILE_NAME);
        }
    }
}

public SqliteDataStore()
{
    _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DBPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
    // Fails trying to perform this action:
    _database.CreateTableAsync<GeneratorTable>().Wait();
    _database.CreateTableAsync<TagTable>().Wait();
}
```

The full source can be viewed [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/melance/TheRandomizer.Mobile).

Stack trace:

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() at
>   TheRandomizer.Services.SqliteDataStore..ctor() at
>   TheRandomizer.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.get_DataStore() at
>   TheRandomizer.ViewModels.GeneratorListViewModel.ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()

Comment: what is the value of DBPath?

Comment: @Jason I added the code for the DBPath after changing it based on Martin's idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

I have tested your code locally and saw the behavior is actually happening and after some debugging I think I might have two reasons:

First, the constructor has only the `SQLiteOpenFlags.Create` flag. Apparently this does not give you any other permissions including read/write. Instead, you can either omit this second argument altogether:

```
_database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DBPath);
```

Or include explicit `ReadWrite` flag (I also included the `FullMutex` flag as it is recommended for async connection):

```
_database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(
     DBPath, 
     SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | 
     SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex | 
     SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite );
```

Second problem occurs when creating the `GeneratorTable` table in DB. SQLite does not know how to store the `Version` property as it is a custom `GeneratorVersion` type. So you will probably have to break it down to simple properties or add an `[Ignore]` attribute.

## Original answer

I have checked your source code and found out you are trying to store the database in the `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` folder. For UWP this actually resolves to `C:\Users\$Username$\Documents`, which a UWP app does not have access to as it is running in a sandbox and does not have access to.

Instead, you must use the application's data folder (which you probably actually intended to):

```
Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: Tried this and unfortunately got the same exception.

Comment: @Lance I have updated my answer with proper solution :-)

Comment: Was my answer to thanks a bunch